# fastest way to do 1 billion queries on millions of rows

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, amazon-rds

I'm running a PHP script that searches through a relatively large MySQL instance with a table with millions of rows to find terms like "diabetes mellitus" in a column `description` that has a full text index on it. However, after one day I'm only through a couple hundred queries so it seems like my approach is never going to work. The entries in the `description` column are on average 1000 characters long.

I'm trying to figure out my next move and I have a few questions:

1. My MySQL table has unnecessary columns in it that aren't being queried. Will remove those affect performance?
2. I assume running this locally rather than on RDS will dramatically increase performance? I have a decent macbook, but I chose RDS since cost isn't an issue, and I tried to run on an instance that was better than the my Macbook.
3. Would using a compiled language like Go rather than PHP do more than the 5-10x boost people report in test examples? That is, given my task is there any reason to think a static language would produce 100X or more speed improvements?
4. Should I put the data in a text or CSV file rather than MySQL? Is using MySQL just causing unnecessary overhead?

---

This is the query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM text_table 
WHERE match(description) against("+diabetes +mellitus" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Here's the line of output of EXPLAIN for the query, showing the optimizer is utilizing the FULLTEXT index:

```
1   SIMPLE  text_table  fulltext    idx idx 0   NULL    1   Using where
```

The RDS instance is **db.m4.10xlarge** which has 160GB of RAM. The InnoDB buffer pool is typically about 75% of RAM on an RDS instance, which make it 120GB.

The text_table status is:

```
           Name: text_table
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 26000630
 Avg_row_length: 2118
    Data_length: 55079485440
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 247808
      Data_free: 6291456
 Auto_increment: 29328‌​568
    Create_time: 2018-01-12 00:49:44
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```

This indicates the table has about 26 million rows, and the size of data and indexes is 51.3GB, but this doesn't include the FT index.

For the size of the FT index, query:

```
SELECT stat_value * @@innodb_page_size 
FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats 
WHERE table_name='text_table' 
AND index_name = 'FTS_DOC_ID_INDEX' 
AND stat_name='size'
```

The size of the FT index is `480247808`.

Comment: Please show your MySQL query. I suspect you are not utilizing the fulltext index. I also think you are using PHP but you could do this in MySQL only and speed up things drastically. This question(s) is also too broad and opinion attracting.

Comment: You would need to specify where the bottleneck actually was before someone could attempt to answer some of those points - but overall this question is too broad. Can you get more specific once you have the bottleneck identified, e.g. provide the code for that part.

Comment: Are you hitting the database with 1-query = 1 search? Could you create a second table with all of the things you want to query and hit them all up in a single query. The extra columns on the table shouldn't matter, MySQL, theoretically, should be hitting the index, not the table. Besides sharing your current query, please also share the explain.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM text_table WHERE match(description) against("+diabetes +mellitus" IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: Is this a batch operation or something that's user-facing? If it's batched you have a lot of latitude here, you can restructure your database to be query friendly. If it's user-facing you'll need to evaluate other indexing methods, even using tools like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co) as an accelerator. Your RDS instance may or may not be faster than your local machine depending on the server type you're using. Some of Amazon's high-end machines can mop the floor with a high-end MacBook, 64 cores and 512GB of memory will beat any notebook in the world, easily.

Comment: @tadman It is batched. It's NOT user-facing.

Comment: @DanFromGermany how do I know if I'm hitting my fulltext index?

Comment: Use explain:  `EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM text_table......`

Comment: @DanFromGermany  `1 SIMPLE text_table fulltext idx idx 0 NULL 1 Using where`

Comment: You could always spin up a huge instance, dump this whole thing into memory, query it aggressively, then shut that instance down. Even the most ridiculously huge Amazon instances are still under $5/hr. so if this takes a day of processing time that might be worth it versus several weeks against an SSD-backed store.

Comment: How long does a single query execute? How do you query each query and what do you do in between. Store results (id) in PHP ? How do you get the search terms?  Doubt MySQL itself is the problem, your query is too

Comment: Another question: what is your current RDS instance size? And how does the size of the table compare to the available buffer pool size? Please report `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'text_table'\G`

Comment: @tadman that's what i'd like to do. Could you point me to a reference on how to do what you say? I.e., to do the full thing in MySQL? I want to query the `text_table` on all combinations of two other tables with 100K rows each. So, 100K x 100K = 1 billion strings. So, `SELECT id FROM text_table WHERE match(description) against("+ 'table1.field1' + 'table2.field2' " IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: @BillKarwin db.m4.10xlarge

Comment: Is this spoken language text, or some kind of machine readable data you're just using a full-text index on out of convenience?

Comment: @DanFromGermany each query takes 1 second to 30 seconds. Even 1 second is too long as 1 billion seconds = 11,000 days. I store the results in another MySQL table in the same database. I get the search terms from yet another table.

Comment: @tadman spoken language text. I'm using a fulltext index because I thought that would speed up the queries and it seems to, but just not enough when there are many queries.

Comment: I'm still not sure MySQL is the right tool for the job here, nor the right approach in general. You may find that ripping through the plain-text source documents and classifying each document individually is faster than smashing them all into a database, indexing them, and then hitting that index up a billion times. This is the sort of thing map-reduce type approaches work well at (e.g. Hadoop, `xargs`, etc.)

Comment: @BillKarwin `text_table InnoDB 10 Compact 26000630 2118 55079485440 0 480247808 6291456 29328568 2018-01-12 00:49:44 NULL NULL utf8_general_ci NULL  `

Comment: I suspect your constraint has a lot to do with the code you have written too. You probably have to find a way to run queries in a few dozen sessions concurrently. Take advantage of the 40 CPU cores.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for editing my question. I added to it the size of the FT index which is 480247808, which I assume is 460Mb. Is that big? How can I take advantage of the 40 CPUs? Can you provide some clues on how run concurrent queries?

Comment: @DanFromGermany and others, with joint efforts after the subsequent question edits I think the question itself has been improved and all those down-votes could be reverted. Would you agree? BTW, slow MySQL FTS queries are also reported by others: https://hackernoon.com/dont-waste-your-time-with-mysql-full-text-search-61f644a54dfa .

Comment: @andrews i never downvoted but agree it got a good question now

Answer (score 2):

Following up on comments above about concurrent queries.

If the query is taking 30 seconds to execute, then the programming language you use for the client app won't make any difference.

I'm a bit skeptical that the query is really taking 1 to 30 seconds to execute. I've tested MySQL fulltext search, and I found a search runs in under 1 second even on my laptop. See my presentation https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

It's possible that it's not the query that's taking so long, but it's the code you have written that submits the queries. What else is your code doing?

How are you measuring the query performance? Are you using MySQL's query profiler? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html This will help isolate how long it takes MySQL to execute the query, so you can compare to how long it takes for the rest of your PHP code to run.

Using PHP is going to be single-threaded, so you are running one query at a time, serially. The RDS instance you are using has 40 CPU cores, so you should be able to many concurrent queries at a time. But each query would need to be run by its own client.

So one idea would be to split your input search terms into at least 40 subsets, and run your PHP search code against each respective subset. MySQL should be able to run the concurrent queries fine. Perhaps there will be a slight overhead, but this will be more than compensated for by the parallel execution.

You can split your search terms manually into separate files, and then run your PHP script with each respective file as the input. That would be a straightforward way of solving this.

But to get really professional, learn to use a tool like [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run the 40 concurrent processes and split your input over these processes automatically.